# Pagination with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I'm using Codeigniter..and i'm new to this. What i'm trying to do is to use pagination in my code but the problem is the pagination link is not shown at the bottom.

**My Controller:**

```
public function dsbds() 
        {    
             $this->load->library('pagination');
             $this->load->model('admin_model');
             $result_per_page = 1;  // the number of result per page
             $config['base_url'] = base_url() . '/admin/';
             $config['total_rows'] = $this->admin_model->dsbds();
             $config['per_page'] = $result_per_page;
             $this->pagination->initialize($config);

             $datatable = $this->admin_model->dsbds($result_per_page, $this->uri->segment(3));
             $this->load->view('admin/danhsachbds', array(
                'bds' => $datatable,
                'result_per_page' => $result_per_page
            ));


        }
```

**My Model:**

```
public function dsbds($limit, $offset)
        {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        $q = $this->db->query("SELECT bds.id, duan.tenduan, loaibds.loai, bds.tieude, phongngu.phongngu, phongtam.phongtam, viewbds.view, huongbds.huong, noithat.noithat, bds.dientich, bds.gia, donvibds.donvi, bds.noidung, duan.slugda, bds.slugbds, bds.datecreate, bds.dateupdate FROM bds LEFT JOIN duan ON duan.id=bds.tenduan LEFT JOIN loaibds ON loaibds.id=bds.loai LEFT JOIN phongngu ON phongngu.id=bds.phongngu LEFT JOIN phongtam ON phongtam.id=bds.phongtam LEFT JOIN viewbds ON viewbds.id=bds.view LEFT JOIN huongbds ON huongbds.id=bds.huong LEFT JOIN noithat ON noithat.id=bds.noithat LEFT JOIN donvibds ON donvibds.id=bds.donvi ORDER BY bds.id DESC");

             if($q->num_rows() > 0)
                 return $q->result();
             return false;
        }
```

**My View:**

```
    <table>

     <tbody>

      <?php foreach($bds as $d) { ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $d->id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $d->tenduan; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $d->phongngu; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $d->phongtam; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $d->dientich; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $d->noithat; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $d->gia; ?> <?php echo $d->donvi; ?></td>          
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</button> </td>
         </tr>
                        <?php } ?>   
  </tbody>
    <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links();  ?>
  </table>
```

My Error:

Severity: Warning
Message: Missing argument 1 for Admin_Model::dsbds(), called in /application/controllers/admin.php on line 231 and defined
Filename: models/admin_model.php

Severity: Warning
Message: Missing argument 2 for Admin_Model::dsbds(), called in /application/controllers/admin.php on line 231 and defined
Filename: models/admin_model.php

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: limit
Filename: models/admin_model.php
Line Number: 316

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: offset
Filename: models/admin_model.php
Line Number: 316

**Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /code/system/libraries/Pagination.php on line 124**

Answer (score 0):

First of all $result_per_page is not defined in the controller function. You should define it inside the function. Also $this->uri->segment(3) does not seems to be exists in your case. What is the url of page, you are trying. You should count url segments again. Well, i am sure you are testing first page, and it does not has paging segment (3rd) in this case.